# django summernote not increases height and not draggable

Tags: django, summernote

I am using `django-summernote` in one of my django website and when my text is too long it appears in scrolling box instead of increasing the size.

It does not have any draggable point on the bottom like it should be in text area. It is fixed in height. If I increase the height from SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG it will give me scroll with same height.

I want to increase the height of the summernote if text increases or I can drag and increase its height.

If anyone know how can I do that or how can I customize it will be great

Comment: Please show us your summemote config...

Comment: SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '400px',
}

Comment: @RajaSimon that is my config

Comment: You have to include some minimal code! Do you have `| safe` in template ? And Your ModelForm ?

Comment: I am using it on admin.. my summer note editor is scrollable I want it to increase height on text increase of it should be increased on draggged

Comment: Are you tried to override the Admin Form ? That is the only way make this to work.. Initially Django admin page set the height of that form. so telling summemote by overriding the form and attached attribute on it..

Comment: Are else you can also do extend the admin page.. So you can directly inject the css rules in the code and try that worked.. this is just the debugging ideas...